# inconveniente extrayendo valores nulos en mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

tengo el siguiente query escrito sobre la base de datos de muestra sakila, usando las tablas film, inventory y rental:

```
select f.film_id,f.title,t.film_id
from film f
left join (select distinct i.film_id
from inventory i
inner join rental r
on i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id) as t
on f.film_id=t.film_id;
```

y el query anterior me produce la siguiente salida:

[image: fragmento]

el primer film_id es de la tabla film y el segundo film_id es del subquery t
y mi objetivo es tomar los films que tienen null en t.film_id

pero al momento de agregar al query

```
where t.film_id=null
```

o

```
having t.film_id=null
```

no me produce salida alguna, es decir, no da error, solo devuelve una tabla vacia.

apreciaria mucho que me ayudaran a saber donde esta fallando mi query, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las evaluaciones de campos `null` debes con hacerlas con `is null` o `is not null`

`where t.film_id is null`

Answer (score 2):

### NULL Palabras clave

`NULL` también se puede utilizar como palabra clave al realizar operaciones booleanas en valores que incluyen NULL. La palabra clave ***“IS / IS NOT”*** se usa junto con la palabra `NULL` para dichos fines. La sintaxis básica cuando `null` se usa como palabra clave es la siguiente

```
`comlumn_name 'IS NULL
`comlumn_name 'IS NOT NULL
```

### AQUÍ

***“IS NULL”*** es la palabra clave que realiza la comparación booleana. Devuelve verdadero si el valor proporcionado es NULO y falso si el valor proporcionado no es NULO.

***“NOT NULL”*** es la palabra clave que realiza la comparación booleana. Devuelve verdadero si el valor proporcionado no es NULO y falso si el valor proporcionado es nulo.